# CSS positioning: container always 60px off browser bottom, but scrollable

Tags: css, positioning

I am trying to position a large container div 60 pixels **above** the browser bottom so as to make room for a video stream and still images, very similar to [this](http://www.damienhirst.com/) solution here.

Unlike the common sticky/fixed type footer, the container is kept in its place on visiting the page and subsequent browser resize - but can be scrolled up for users wanting to explore the site's content.

Looking at the sample site, I can see that the CSS property "top" changes on browser resize, but I can't find the *mechanism* that accomplishes this.

How should I go about achieving this kind of *elasticity*?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with Javascript along the lines of

```
setTop = function(e) {
    document.getElementById('content').style.marginTop = window.innerHeight - 60;
};

window.onresize = setTop;
```

Full working example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #content {
      width: 80%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      border: 1px solid black;
      height: 100%;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content">
  Here is the content...
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  setTop = function(e) {
      document.getElementById('content').style.marginTop = window.innerHeight - 60;
  };

  setTop();
  window.onresize = setTop;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for that quick answer, JavaScript it shall be then; I'll give that a try.

Comment: No luck [with this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FGv5f/). I can set margin-top manually (fiddle) on the #container as one would expect, but not programmatically via JavaScript. However, your JavaScript example does work in all browsers when I tried it in a new document. Could there be some kind of conflict?

Comment: maybe this is just an issue with the fiddle?

Comment: Does not work on localhost testing either; I have not yet seen JSFIDDLE giving wrong output with simple issues like this. What is strange is that I can manually set the margin top on the container as I wish, but not via JavaScript. Got to do some reading, I guess...